# UISearchBar not showing scope bar when setting in storyboard

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, uisearchbar

I want to add searchBar with scope bar to the top of tableview, I build the app with storyboard. It works well before I add the scope bar.

[image]

Then I check the checkBox in the attributes inspector and add two scope titles:
[image]

the searchbar turns out to be this way:

[image]
like something goes wrong.

I remove the setting and try it with code:

```html
self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"title1",@"title2",@"title3"];
```

It seems works well except the color of the copeButtons:
[image]

I am using  XCode6.1 and the deployment target is 7.0, does any one have ideas?

Comment: Thanks man. It works for me

Answer (score -1):

If you are using story board your view Controller should be controlled by Navigation Controller and Use document outline drag and drop as you want.